# Why is this airfoil curved upwards on the bottom part of the airfoil?

Tags: lift, airfoil

[image]
<sup>Image source [datawiki.net](http://www.datwiki.net/images2/Symmetrical-Airfoil.jpg)</sup>

Is this to slow down airspeed. I know that the high pressure and low pressure above and below the wing both contribute to downwash, but how does this airfoil form downwash?

Comment: What do you mean by 'slow down airspeed'?

Comment: @Ethan If you can post a link to an image then you can post the image directly without needing to upload it. I know others have asked you about this before. What is stopping you? (This isn't an upload issue so please don't blame your laptop)

Comment: Also good to indicate image sources. (I grabbed it from Ethan's original post.)

Answer (score 7):

Downwash is simply the deflection of air due to airfoil (or wing etc.)

Symmetric airfoils don't produce downwash (or lift) at zero angle of attack.

[image: Airfoil Zero angle of attack]

Source: oppositelock.kinja.com

However, as the angle of attack is increased, the (symmetric) airfoil produces both.

[image: Airfoil positive angle of attakc]

Source: *Effect of angle of attack on flow field and body forces* by Paul Nathan from youtube.com

Symmetrical airfoils are used in rotary wing applications, vertical tail (and rudder) etc.

Comment: Does a conventional airfoil produce lift at a zero degree angle of attack? I mean airfoils that are curved downwards on the top and have no curve on the bottom.

Comment: @Ethan *Cambered* airfoils produce lift at zero angle of attack.